# How to safely use g_variant_iter_loop with data received via DBUS

Tags: c, glib, dbus

My stack trace looks like this

```
/usr/lib/libglib-2.0.so.0(g_variant_iter_loop+0xb4)
/usr/lib/libglib-2.0.so.0(g_variant_get_int32+0x1c) 
/usr/lib/libglib-2.0.so.0(g_variant_type_is_subtype_of+0x3c)
```

and the code for it is like:

```
while ((NULL != iterator) && (true == g_variant_iter_loop (iterator, "y", &extractedValue)))
{
  // do something with extractedValue
}
```

The data is received via DBUS using a GVariant.
Maybe i'm not using glib API properly, but this fails only like 1% of the cases. 
Am i doing something wrong, or i am missing something ?

Comment: I don't know which error are you getting, but the documentation https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-GVariant.html#g-variant-iter-loop recommends g_variant_iter_next for "integer and string types".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When only one element is expected, is better to use

```
if(iter != NULL) {
    g_variant_iter_next (iterator, "u", &value);
}
```